# Bamboo errors when running batch file, but I can run it manually fine

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, bamboo

I have a batch file with the following contents:

```
@echo ON
echo "start"
echo "${bamboo.agentWorkingDirectory}"
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
cd "${bamboo.build.working.directory}/server"
CALL npm install --msvs_version=2012
exit
```

I use this batch file to install OracleDB via Bamboo.

When I run this batch file manually, everything installs fine and all is happy. However, when I get Bamboo to run the exact same batch file, I get the following error:

```
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:04    E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EC-ECB-BE\server\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild ) 
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:06    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:06      njsOracle.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:06      njsPool.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      njsConnection.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      njsMessages.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiEnv.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiEnvImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiException.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiExceptionImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiConnImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiDateTimeArrayImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiPoolImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiStmtImpl.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07      dpiUtils.cpp
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07    e:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\ec-ecb-be\server\node_modules\oracledb\src\njs\src\njsConnection.h(54): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node.h': No such file or directory (..\src\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EC-ECB-BE\server\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07    ..\src\njs\src\njsPool.cpp(51): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node.h': No such file or directory [E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EC-ECB-BE\server\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
build   15-Oct-2015 16:53:07    ..\src\njs\src\njsOracle.cpp(51): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node.h': No such file or directory [E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EC-ECB-BE\server\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! build error 
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! cwd E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EC-ECB-BE\server\node_modules\oracledb
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    gyp ERR! not ok 
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--msvs_version=2012"
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    npm ERR! node v0.12.7
error   15-Oct-2015 16:53:08    npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
```

There must be a difference between the regular windows environment and the bamboo environment that I'm just not setting. I have the following environment variables set in the Bamboo task:

```
TEMP="C:\temp" TMP="C:\temp" GYP_MSVS_VERSION="2012"   
OCI_LIB_DIR="C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\lib\msvc"   
OCI_INC_DIR="C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\include"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the beer and pizza offer for real?

Comment: Yep - absolutely. This is still racking my brain and figured this might be a good incentive :P

Answer (score 0):

Run: `node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\n‌​ode-gyp.js" rebuild`. 
That should produce an error.

If it does NOT produce an error, `npm_config_node_gyp` might be getting modified to cwd by Bamboo. In this case, set the correct value as the environment variable.

If it does give out an error, check for `node.h` file or a `src` folder in the `%USERPROFILE%/.node-gyp/` directory, hopefully it will not exist and re-installing `node-gyp` should make it work.

Comment: Hmm, this is a fairly good lead from the sounds of it. Running `node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\n‌​ode-gyp.js" rebuild` does indeed produce the error. However, when I search for `node.h` and the `src` folder I can find both of them. They exist in `%USERPROFILE%/.node-gyp/0.12.7/src`. Could it be possible that Bamboo is not seeing these? If so, how can I set that?

The error I get when running the rebuild command is: `gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Windows\system32) while trying to load binding.gyp`

Comment: Also, running the rebuild command still fails even after reinstalling node-gyp (with the same error as I listed before).

Comment: Try running the rebuild command with: ` npm config set msvs_version 2012 --global`. That should resolve the `binding.gyp` error. Regardless, Bamboo is most likely not seeing the src files. You could start with setting HOME or USERPROFILE as environment variables.

Comment: Hmmm, setting msvs_version 2012 still didn't seem to resolve that error rebuilding node-gyp :/